Spinner probability question with repetition (HS)
I found this problem in a 10th grade math text book in a section about using permutations to solve probability problems.

The book presents the answer as $$ \frac{1}{110880} $$
Which is 1 over the number of ways to arrange the 12 colors accounting for repetition. This seems undoubtedly incorrect to me.
I suggested to a colleague that the solution is simply:
$$ \frac{3}{12} \times \frac{5}{12} \times \frac{3}{12} \times \frac{1}{12} \approx 0.002$$
They suggested that that this doesn't account for order because you could rearrange them and get the same answer. I'm still not convinced that this matters. Similarly to how fundamental counting principle would result in the same answer no matter the order you arranged the numbers.
Either way I'm curious if there is a way to solve this using permutations. Doesn't seem like it to me, I don't ever recall learning how to account for repetitions when you're restricted, i.e. spinning four times in this case, instead of twelve times.
And the book answer is definitely wrong right?
Thanks in advance for everyone's help.

You're right. Your formula is right and it's not at all clear why the solution should have anything to do with the possible arrangements of the 12 colors on the spinner.

As a sanity check, I would suggest that you discuss a simpler spinner problem so that they could see how the "intended" approach falls apart. In particular, suppose that the spinner is simply divided into 4 quarters, one of each color, and again we ask for the probability of getting blue, red, green, yellow in that order. Your approach yields the correct answer of $1/4^4 = 1/256$ whereas the suggested alternative gives $1/4! = 1/24$.

You are right as Ben Grossmann already mentioned. Your colleague's argument that rearranging yields the same result is not an argument against your proposed probability. It only says that picking blue, red, green, yellow in that order is just as (un)likely as picking red, yellow, green, blue or any other order.
I'd like to give a bit of a different perspective on this, such that you can convince your colleague. Imagine the spinner having not only colors but also numbers from $1$ to $12$.

We are going to spin $4$ times and in each spin the arrow points at exactly one numbers. If we write down these numbers, it will look like this:
$$(a,b,c,d)$$
where $a$ denotes the number of the first spin, $b$ of the second, $c$ of the third, and $d$ of the fourth. For example,
$$(7,11,5,12)$$
is the outcome that your first spin lands on $7$, you second  on $11$, your third on $5$, and your fourth on $12$.
In total there are $12 \cdot 12 \cdot 12 \cdot 12 = 12^4 = 20736$ different outcomes and any of these outcomes appears with probability
$$\frac{1}{12^4}$$
since each outcome appears as likely as any other.
Now you just have to count all the outcomes which are possible for the scenario of picking blue, red, green, yellow in this order. Those are
$$
\begin{aligned}
&(1, 2, 8, 4)\\
&(1, 2, 9, 4)\\
&(1, 2, 10, 4)\\
&(1, 3, 8, 4)\\
&(1, 3, 9, 4)\\
&(1, 3, 10, 4)\\
&(1, 5, 8, 4)\\
&(1, 5, 9, 4)\\
&(1, 5, 10, 4)\\
&(1, 6, 8, 4)\\
&(1, 6, 9, 4)\\
&(1, 6, 10, 4)\\
&(1, 7, 8, 4)\\
&(1, 7, 9, 4)\\
&(1, 7, 10, 4)\\
&(11, 2, 8, 4)\\
&(11, 2, 9, 4)\\
&(11, 2, 10, 4)\\
&(11, 3, 8, 4)\\
&(11, 3, 9, 4)\\
&(11, 3, 10, 4)\\
&(11, 5, 8, 4)\\
&(11, 5, 9, 4)\\
&(11, 5, 10, 4)\\
&(11, 6, 8, 4)\\
&(11, 6, 9, 4)\\
&(11, 6, 10, 4)\\
&(11, 7, 8, 4)\\
&(11, 7, 9, 4)\\
&(11, 7, 10, 4)\\
&(12, 2, 8, 4)\\
&(12, 2, 9, 4)\\
&(12, 2, 10, 4)\\
&(12, 3, 8, 4)\\
&(12, 3, 9, 4)\\
&(12, 3, 10, 4)\\
&(12, 5, 8, 4)\\
&(12, 5, 9, 4)\\
&(12, 5, 10, 4)\\
&(12, 6, 8, 4)\\
&(12, 6, 9, 4)\\
&(12, 6, 10, 4)\\
&(12, 7, 8, 4)\\
&(12, 7, 9, 4)\\
&(12, 7, 10, 4)\\
\end{aligned}
$$
which are $45$ in total. Adding up all those probabilities leaves you with the probability of
$$45\cdot\frac{1}{12^4}=\frac{3}{12}\cdot\frac{5}{12}\cdot\frac{3}{12}\cdot\frac{1}{12}$$
as you suggested.
Now to convince your colleague here is the list of again $45$ possible outcomes to pick red, yellow, green, blue in that order:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&(2, 4, 1, 8)\\
&(2, 4, 1, 9)\\
&(2, 4, 1, 10)\\
&(2, 4, 11, 8)\\
&(2, 4, 11, 9)\\
&(2, 4, 11, 10)\\
&(2, 4, 12, 8)\\
&(2, 4, 12, 9)\\
&(2, 4, 12, 10)\\
&(3, 4, 1, 8)\\
&(3, 4, 1, 9)\\
&(3, 4, 1, 10)\\
&(3, 4, 11, 8)\\
&(3, 4, 11, 9)\\
&(3, 4, 11, 10)\\
&(3, 4, 12, 8)\\
&(3, 4, 12, 9)\\
&(3, 4, 12, 10)\\
&(5, 4, 1, 8)\\
&(5, 4, 1, 9)\\
&(5, 4, 1, 10)\\
&(5, 4, 11, 8)\\
&(5, 4, 11, 9)\\
&(5, 4, 11, 10)\\
&(5, 4, 12, 8)\\
&(5, 4, 12, 9)\\
&(5, 4, 12, 10)\\
&(6, 4, 1, 8)\\
&(6, 4, 1, 9)\\
&(6, 4, 1, 10)\\
&(6, 4, 11, 8)\\
&(6, 4, 11, 9)\\
&(6, 4, 11, 10)\\
&(6, 4, 12, 8)\\
&(6, 4, 12, 9)\\
&(6, 4, 12, 10)\\
&(7, 4, 1, 8)\\
&(7, 4, 1, 9)\\
&(7, 4, 1, 10)\\
&(7, 4, 11, 8)\\
&(7, 4, 11, 9)\\
&(7, 4, 11, 10)\\
&(7, 4, 12, 8)\\
&(7, 4, 12, 9)\\
&(7, 4, 12, 10)\\
\end{aligned}
$$
This again leaves you with a probability of
$$45\cdot\frac{1}{12^4}=\frac{5}{12}\cdot\frac{1}{12}\cdot\frac{3}{12}\cdot\frac{3}{12}$$
Now, I'd like to propose that you try to write down those lists by yourself. Not to annoy you, but I think it is valuable to learn the systematic behind it. Unfortunately, I've seen too many people struggle with it.
Let's pick the ordering blue, red, green. Firstly, you order the numbers by colors:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\color{blue}{\text{blue}}&= 1,11,12\\
\color{red}{\text{red}}&= 2,3,5,6,7\\
\color{green}{\text{green}}&= 8,9,10\\
\end{aligned}
$$
You start with the lowest number in each group, namely
$$(1,2,8)$$
and then go through all the possiblities. This can be done by cycling through the digits always starting from the back. How this works is indicated by the colored numbers. A number is colored, if it has changed its entry compared to the line above; indicating the cycling. (The numbers in the very first line are colored only for better illustration.)
$$
\begin{aligned}
&( \color{blue}{1}, \color{red}{2}, \color{green}{8} )\\
&( {1}, {2}, \color{green}{9} )\\
&( {1}, {2}, \color{green}{10} )\\
&( {1}, \color{red}{3}, \color{green}{8} )\\
&( {1}, {3}, \color{green}{9} )\\
&( {1}, {3}, \color{green}{10} )\\
&( {1}, \color{red}{5}, \color{green}{8} )\\
&( {1}, {5}, \color{green}{9} )\\
&( {1}, {5}, \color{green}{10} )\\
&( {1}, \color{red}{6}, \color{green}{8} )\\
&( {1}, {6}, \color{green}{9} )\\
&( {1}, {6}, \color{green}{10} )\\
&( {1}, \color{red}{7}, \color{green}{8} )\\
&( {1}, {7}, \color{green}{9} )\\
&( {1}, {7}, \color{green}{10} )\\
&( \color{blue}{11}, \color{red}{2}, \color{green}{8} )\\
&( {11}, {2}, \color{green}{9} )\\
&( {11}, {2}, \color{green}{10} )\\
&( {11}, \color{red}{3}, \color{green}{8} )\\
&( {11}, {3}, \color{green}{9} )\\
&( {11}, {3}, \color{green}{10} )\\
&( {11}, \color{red}{5}, \color{green}{8} )\\
&( {11}, {5}, \color{green}{9} )\\
&( {11}, {5}, \color{green}{10} )\\
&( {11}, \color{red}{6}, \color{green}{8} )\\
&( {11}, {6}, \color{green}{9} )\\
&( {11}, {6}, \color{green}{10} )\\
&( {11}, \color{red}{7}, \color{green}{8} )\\
&( {11}, {7}, \color{green}{9} )\\
&( {11}, {7}, \color{green}{10} )\\
&( \color{blue}{12}, \color{red}{2}, \color{green}{8} )\\
&( {12}, {2}, \color{green}{9} )\\
&( {12}, {2}, \color{green}{10} )\\
&( {12}, \color{red}{3}, \color{green}{8} )\\
&( {12}, {3}, \color{green}{9} )\\
&( {12}, {3}, \color{green}{10} )\\
&( {12}, \color{red}{5}, \color{green}{8} )\\
&( {12}, {5}, \color{green}{9} )\\
&( {12}, {5}, \color{green}{10} )\\
&( {12}, \color{red}{6}, \color{green}{8} )\\
&( {12}, {6}, \color{green}{9} )\\
&( {12}, {6}, \color{green}{10} )\\
&( {12}, \color{red}{7}, \color{green}{8} )\\
&( {12}, {7}, \color{green}{9} )\\
&( {12}, {7}, \color{green}{10} )\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Notice that you are always cycling with the last digit, every now and then with the second last digit and ongoingly less cycling with the numbers towards the front. This is an easy and effective method to find all the possibilities instead of stumbling around with numbers.
Also, you may see much better now, why there are really $3\cdot 5 \cdot 3$ outcomes for the event of picking blue, red, green in that order.
